# XeLaTeX fonts don't work well on Windows?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, templates, small-caps

I have recently downloaded the template for a CV from http://www.latextemplates.com/template/plasmati-graduate-cv. It is supposed to be compiled using XeLaTeX, with previous installation of the Fontin font which can be downloaded from http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html.

In Linux everything works great, but under Windows it is a catastophe: all letters are written in small caps. The problem is in this line:

```
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin} % Main document font
```

I have contacted the author of the template and he has suggested that I use Fontin Regular instead of Fontin SmallCaps:

```
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin Regular]{Fontin} % Main document font
```

But, if I do that I am unable to use `\textsc` at all. Does anyone have any suggestion?

**Addendum:** One other thing. I have noticed that within this enviroment I cannot use some accents, e.g.`\v{c}`, `\'{c}` etc. Is this normal?

Comment: Use `\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin Regular} `

Comment: With regards to your addendum, characters with those accents may not be available in Fontin.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Wanna convert you comment into an answer and get the Q off the list of unanswered?

Answer (score 5):

Use `\setmainfont{Fontin Regular}[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]` (newer syntax), or
 `\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin Regular}` (older syntax).

Comment: Before the discussion gets to heated: I will edit the answer and mention both syntax

Comment: @Manuel: you didn't corrected a typo or a faulty brace but made a change in the meaning, a switch from an older to a newer syntax. In such cases I prefer a comment to an edit.